# django template table rows do not collapse

Tags: django, templates

I can not work-out what I am doing wrong with collapsing certain rows of my table.

Can you advice how can I correct it so I can collapse rows marked in red ?

I guess I have placed collapse tag in wrong place or have not used  again ? However can I use table in table ?

**my template:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <h3><a href="">{% for project in projects %}{{ project.project_name }}{% endfor %}</a></h3>

    <table class="table table-striped table table-bordered table table-hover table table-condensed">
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <!-- row with zone names -->
        {% for z in zones %}
            <td style="width:40px" align="center">{{ z.zone_name }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>

        <!-- rows with stage names -->
        {% for trstage in trstages %}
            <tr>
                <td style="width:40px"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{ trstage }}">{{ trstage.stage_name }}</a></td>
                <!--  row with stage value  -->
                {% for stage in trstage.stages %}
                        {% for zone in zones|dictsort:"zone_name" %}
                            {% if zone == stage.zone %}
                                <td style="width:40px" align="center">{{ stage.substage_sum.sum }}</td>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            <div id="collapse{{ trstage }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <!-- rows with substages names -->
                {% for trsubstage in trstage.related_trsubstages %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ trsubstage.substage_name }}</td>
                <!-- row with substage value -->
                {% for substage in trsubstage.substages_related %}
                    {% for zone in zones %}
                        {% if zone == substage.stage.zone %}
                        <td style="width:40px" align="center">{{ substage.substage_value }}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is link to my current template view:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the id of your trstage to the href and id of the divs. I did something similar in my project and it worked. I hope it works for you too. Like this,

```
<div id="{{ trstage.id.value }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

and

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{ trstage.id.value }}">{{ trstage.stage_name }}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not help.

Comment: i am not sure why it doesn't help. It worked for me. Check if the trstage.id is empty. or just try trstage.id and not trstage.id.value.

Comment: I have tried trstage.id and links display right values but collapse functionality does not do anything.

Comment: <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{ entity.id.value }} "> {{ entity.Name.value }} </a> The only difference I see in yours and mine is the extra attribute data-parent="#accordion." If that doesn't help either, then I am sorry I don't know what else is going wrong.

Comment: I have just added <div class="panel-body"> after <div id="collapse{{ trstage.id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse"> and now collapse do something but it expands and collapse the area between p0 and table. So, I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Is it something to do with <table> itself ?

Comment: <div class="panel panel-default"> <div><a>your anchor tag </a></div> <div class="panel-collapse collapse"> your collapsible code </div>  </div>. Enclose your <div class="panel-default"> before your for tag. I hope this helps.